# Populate text boxes with data

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to create it so that when a button is pressed, it reads an ID from a text box and and then puts the selected data from the SQL database into a series of text boxes.

Here is my current code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand("select * from Personal_Details WHERE PersonID= " +
                       personIDTextBox, sqlConnection1);
    sqlConnection1.Open();

    SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (read.Read())
    {
        Txt_FirstName.Text = (read["FIRSTNAME"].ToString());
    }
    read.Close();
}
```

I am a novice, so I have been following tutorials and so far none have worked so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should specify the UI technology you are using.

Comment: You should get rid of [Little Bobby Tables](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) by using [parametrized queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take Text property from TextBox instead of `personIDTextBox` you have to get the Text property by `personIDTextBox.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things here, like you have not provided connection string for you connection, and second is that, if you `personIDTextBox` is name of your text box, you should use its value using the `Text` property.

Additionally you should use the `using` statements to get the objects disposed automatically.

```
        string connectionString = "You connection string to database";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // Open the SqlConnection.
            con.Open();
            //
            // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
            //
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Personal_Details WHERE PersonID= " + personIDTextBox.Text, con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Txt_FirstName.Text = (reader["FIRSTNAME"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Note: You should use command parameters instead of naked sql statement, as they are prone to `SqlInjections`

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong query because this query can be return more records. If query will return more record  you will be assigned last record.

Edit query  : `Select TOP 1 * From bla bla` this query return one record.

so, you can use

```
    while (read.Read())
    {
        Txt_FirstName.Text=reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FIRSTNAME"));
    }
```

Or

```
    //Because will return one record , you don't need to return records using while 
      if(read.read())
      {              
         Txt_FirstName.Text=reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FIRSTNAME"));
      }
```

Note : The best way to read data in DataReader

```
reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FIRSTNAME"))
```